# How to use quartz.net in the genexus project？

Tags: quartz.net, genexus

I want to use quartz.net to implement scheduled tasks in the genexus project. How do I do this? I downloaded the quartz.net compressed package from the Internet. What should I do next?

Download compressed package from this website：https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/releases

Answer (score 0):

To work with .net libraries, you need to import with tools/application integration/import .net assemblies, and for java, need tools/application integration/import java classes.

Comment: Thank you！The. net assembly has been imported. What should I do then? I'm just a beginner. Is there any reference document that can help me?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is the Getting Started guide. There are also working samples for you to start. https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/quick-start.html